# Design Pattern of a MVC3 web based application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns

I am NEW in MVC3 and designing a web based application and kind of in learning phase. I am building a project where I need to show a list of customers in a web grid.

Now, I need to email a list of customers everyday, whose info (Name) is not updated for more than 6 months. How should I design the application? Do I need to use SQL Server Agent jobs for picking up the list of customers?

Any discussion or idea will be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are actually seeking is how to run background tasks in asp.net mvc. There are many ways this can be done, but Jeff Atwood explained a simple version here well [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/) when designing the badge system for stack overflow.

There are other stuff such as windows services for more intensive processes but you will have a problem when hosting on shared servers.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Yes basically thats what I am asking. I dont want to go with SQL Job Agent procedure.

Comment: Ugh, that's a bad way to go.  Read the comments, people point out lots of problems with it.  And notice how quickly SO moved to a dedicated task.  It didn't even last a year.

Comment: @Andy you cant really run from this method when using a shared host :(.

Comment: @Shawn Mclean Sql Agent was mentioned as a possiblity; that would be better than this method.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to write a windows exe or windows service.  Scheduled the exe with task scheduler or maybe even Sql Agent can fire it off.  Since its just once a day, I don't think a service is necessary.